# how to use the evernote api to retrieve bookmarks?

Tags: bookmarks, evernote

I've stored a bunch of bookmarks on my evernote. Is there a way of using the evernote api to programmatically access all the bookmarks as a list?

I looked through the evernote api documentation and did see any bookma

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you stored your bookmarks. If you've got the URL in the note's URL field, then you can access this directly from the [Note.attributes.sourceURL](http://www.evernote.com/about/developer/api/ref/Types.html#Struct_NoteAttributes) field.